# Proper definition of coordinate ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

In many sources I have read I see that for an irreducible affine variety $V \subseteq K^n$ its coordinate ring is defined to be
$$K[V] = K[x_1, \ldots, x_n] / I(V),$$
where $I(V) = \{f \in K[x_1, \ldots, x_n] : \forall x \in V, f(x) = 0\}$.

My question is, is this the right definition of the coordinate ring and ideal associated with the variety? I'm confused because $V$ can contain different sets of points depending on the field $K$, and we only get the "full picture" when $K$ is algebraically closed. For example, the variety $V = V(x^2 - 2)$ is empty in $\mathbb Q$, but obviously has points in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. So what is $I(V)$? Since $V$ is defined over $\mathbb Q$ (coefficients of the generating polynomials are in $\mathbb Q$), do we have
$$I(V) = \{f \in \mathbb Q[x] : \forall x \in V(\mathbb Q), f(x) = 0\} = \mathbb Q[x],$$
so that $$\mathbb Q[V] = \mathbb Q[x] / \mathbb Q[x] \cong \text{trivial ring}?$$
Or do we have
$$\begin{align*}I(V) &= \{f \in \mathbb Q[x] : \forall x \in V(\bar{\mathbb Q}), f(x) = 0\} \\ &= \{f \in \mathbb Q[x] : \forall x \in V(\mathbb C), f(x) = 0\} \\ &= (x^2 - 2) \subseteq \mathbb Q[x]\end{align*}$$
so that
$$\mathbb Q[V] = \mathbb Q[x] / (x^2 - 2) \cong \mathbb C?$$

Basically, I'm confused as to what points we want to consider to be in $V$ in order to say that $f, g : K[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \to K$ are "equal" on $V$. Do we identify $f \equiv g \in K[V]$ if $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in V(K)$, or is it for all $x \in V(\bar K)$? Is there a standard definition for this?

Comment: Indeed, if you want to work with anything but algebraically closed fields, varieties are probably the wrong setting anyway (you really want schemes).

Comment: I don't know anything about schemes, though :/. I'm in an introductory algebraic geometry class and we're only going through affine varieties so far.

Comment: But are you doing affine varieties over arbitrary fields/rings?

Comment: We're doing affine varieties over arbitrary fields, not rings. But we haven't even gotten to coordinate rings yet; I'm just looking these up for personal research, and I'm trying to get the right definition so that I can continue on to understand other things.

Comment: The thing is that you will very quickly run into some problems. For example, you started with a subset of $K^n$. But if you start from the algebra side, how do you identify your space (as given by an ideal) with a subset of this when the field is not algebraically closed?

Comment: The hacky way one has to do this if you don't want to talk about schemes is as follows. Consider $I(V(\overline{K}))$ where $V(\overline{K})$ is the solutions to $f_1=\cdots=f_n=0$ over $\overline{K}$ inside of $\overline{K}[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$. Then, show that $I(V\overline{K}))$ has generators with coefficients in $K$. Then, $I(V)$ is the ideal of $K[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$ generated by these polynomials wiht $K$-coefficient.s

Comment: So in general for the coordinate ring, do I want to identify two functions if they are equal over $V(\bar K)$ instead of just $V(K)$? @AlexYoucis I think you're saying it should be the first, since you mention $I(V(\bar K))$. Am I understanding you correctly? Also, why does $I(V(\bar K))$ have to have generators with coefficients in $K$?